# how to create individual log files from different ip in the same txt

Tags: shell, tcl, expect

I have already done an expect script. It works well. The script will read a txt file called ip_list. And then running command and output a log file. My question is if there are many different IP address in the txt file, how to modify my code to print out like one IP address for one log file?

```
set f [open "ip_list.txt"]
set addr [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

foreach addr $addr {
if {$addr eq {}} continue;
    set timeout 180
    match_max 1000000
    spawn telnet $addr
    expect {
    "*timed out*"   {puts "Host not responding"; continue}
    "'^]'."                                 {sleep .1}
    }
    expect "*login*"        {send "$user\r"}
    expect "*assword:*"     {send "$pass\r"}
    expect {
    "Login incorrect"   {puts "Bad Password or User"; exit}
    -re {[#>] ?$}           {send "page-off\r"} 
    }
    log_file $customer\-License-$date.log
    expect -re {[#>] ?$}
    send "show clock\r"
    sleep .5
    expect -re {[#>] ?$}
    send "\r"
puts "Connection closed, connecting to next one\r"
    sleep 1
    log_file
expect eof;
}
```

Any idea could help, thank you!

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. Please take care when choosing your tags.

Comment: Try to change from `log_file $customer\-License-$date.log` to `log_file $customer\-License-${date}-${addr}.log`

Comment: @RuslanRakhmanin thank you so much! I forget the {} sign.